# build a bot in Azure online code editor

Tags: c#, azure, bots, azure-qna-maker

I'm experiencing the following error whenever I attempt to build my Azure web app bot online. When I run build.cmd, deploy.cmd immediately fails with the following error. I've not been able to find any information on the web on how to resolve this issue. it's very odd because it goes away the following day. I'm able to build once, and then it fails for all subsequent builds. Very odd.

> build.cmd
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

I am simply relaying information here. In the 'Build a bot' guide, it looks like someone else ran into your exact error above. There is a reply to that comment from someone that was able to circumvent the problem:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-build-online-code-editor?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

> I had the same error when entering build.cmd in the App Service
>   Editor.
>
> For me it worked entering the command directly in the Console in the
>   Azure Portal (under Development Tools in the App Service)
>
> Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's a weird error. But it has a workaround which will not impend your work.

You can go to Web App Bot => App settings. Open the App URL and add SCM into it. This will open up Kudo.

Click on Debug Console => CMD. Navigate to d:/home/site/wwwroot and then enter build.cmd command. This will build your Bot code.

I have recorded above-mentioned steps, watch - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NAtxPCfcPGU&t=5s

Hope this will help you!

Thanks,
Kasam Shaikh

Answer (score 0):

Restart the Entire Web App, Web App Bot and try again.

this happened to me before. then i used this.

also i recommend to use Continous delivery/deployment. you won't able to think about these kind of errors.

Pre... Visual Studio Account, Devops project. you can simply configure. afterthat you don't need to publish at all the time.